# Elasticsearch : Pass multiple values for same field with a date filter

Tags: elasticsearch-6

I'm working on searching employees details based on multiple values for a given field i.e. will pass multiple employee email address/names and also multiple countries for a given request. Now, we need to pull the required details of those employees (based on name, email address and their respective country).

Query works fine with single field value search like an employee name or employee email address, country and a date range. But, it fails to get required response with multiple values for employee name or email address, countries and a date range.

Below is index mapping details :

```
{
emplsampleindex: {
    mappings: {
        employeeinfo: {
        properties: {
            emp_cntry: { type: "keyword" },
            employee_name: { type: "text",
                 fields: { keyword: { type: "keyword" } } },
            email_address: { type: "keyword"},
            hiredate: { type: "date", format: "yyyy-MM-dd" }
          }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

**Working with single value :**

```
 {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [
          {
            "match" : {
              "email_address" : {
                "query" : "raju@test.com",
                "operator" : "OR",
                "prefix_length" : 0,
                "max_expansions" : 50,
                "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
                "lenient" : false,
                "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter" : [
          {
            "range" : {
              "hiredate" : {
                "from" : "2013-08-01",
                "to" : null,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
```

**Not Working with multiple value :**  :

```
{
  "bool": {
    "filter": [
      {
        "range": {
          "hiredate": {
            "from": "2013-08-01",
            "to": null,
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "should": [
      {
        "term": {
          "email_address": {
            "value": "tempemail1@test.com",
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "email_address": {
            "value": "temp@test.com",
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
    "boost": 1.0
  }
}
```

With **should**, we are getting all employee records from 2013-08-01 in elasticsearch and instead of **should**, if I use **must** then we are not getting any result i.e. total hits though we have records for those email_address.

Comment: `should` is an implementation of `logical OR` while `must` is a `logical AND`. Which means when you use `must`, it would try to find all documents having both email ids. What you want works with `should` of course unless you have a document with `email` having multiple `email ids` in a **List**.

Comment: Thanks Kamal, Yes, it working with _should_ but when I add a _filter_ with date range(hiredate), then it's pulling all the employees records from 2013-08-01 to till date instead of pulling only for specific employees as per query.

Comment: @ChetanRamaiah you can try with `terms` along with `filter` kind of same way that I used on you latest question See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58046948/1138192