# Elasticsearch : filter results based on the date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.6, trying to extract multiple results/records based on multiple values (email_address) passed to the query (Bool) on a date range. For ex: I want to extract information about few employees based on their email_address (annie@test.com, charles@test.com, heman@test.com) and from the period i.e project_date (2019-01-01).

I did use should expression but unfortunately it's pulling all the records from elasticsearch based on the date range i.e. it's even pulling other employees information from project_date 2019-01-01.

```
{

  "query": {

    "bool": {

      "should": [

        { "match": { "email_address":   "annie@test.com"        }},

        { "match": { "email_address":   "chalavadi@test.com"        }}

      ],

      "filter": [

        { "range": { "project_date": { "gte": "2019-08-01" }}}

      ]

    }

  }

}
```

I also tried must expression but getting no result. Could you please help me on finding employees using their email_address with the date range?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample data?. So then I can help you out. And also the document structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should(Or) clauses are optional

Quoting from [this](https://engineering.carsguide.com.au/elasticsearch-demystifying-the-bool-query-11da737a4efb) article.
"In a query, if must and filter queries are present, the should query occurrence then helps to influence the score. However, if bool query is in a filter context or has neither must nor filter queries, then at least one of the should queries must match a document."

So in your query should is only influencing the score and not actually filtering the document. You must wrap should in must, or move it in filter(if scoring not required).

```
GET employeeindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "projectdate": {
            "gte": "2019-01-01"
          }
        }
      },
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "email.raw": "abc@text.com"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "email.raw": "efg@text.com"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also replace should clause with terms clause as in @AlwaysSunny's answer.

Comment: Glad could be of help

Comment: I had one more question on search. Should I submit a new post?

Comment: Yes please, Since this is closed, will try to help there

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `terms` and `range`  along with your existing query inside `filter` in more shorter way. Your existing query doesn't work as expected because of `should` clause, it makes your `filter` weaker. **Read more here:**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

```
{
 "query": { 
 "bool": { 
   "filter": [ 
     {
          "terms": {
            "email_address.keyword": [
              "annie@test.com", "chalavedi@test.com"
            ]
          }
      },
      {
          "range": {
            "project_date": {
              "gte": "2019-08-01"
            }
          }
       }
    ]
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried above solution, it didn't work. Looks like I am missing something. Thanks @Always Sunny.

Comment: I didn't get any error but was not getting records. ``` {
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
} ``` Please let me know if I have missed any thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can  see a typo on my answer on project_date  value it was **2019-08001** , corrected now, also if no result come you can tweak email_adress only instead of email_address.keyword but mostly I think it was not returning results because of the typo. Checkout and let me know further

Comment: Sorry for the late response, will definitely try now and keep you posted.

Comment: Ok no problem, take your time mate :)